# Use a font sprite sheet as font in SFML 2.4

Tags: c++, sfml

Is it possible in SFML to take a image with fonts for example

> [image]

I'd take this image and somehow make it be represented as text and use it in either `sf::Text` or `sf::Font`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[No.](https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=5334.0)

SFML font handling is only concerned with normal font files. Sprite sheet fonts could be easily implemented with `sf::Sprite`, though.

Comment: How would I go about doing this then?

Comment: @Lucky38i: you implement it yourself or use an existing library. Here's my implementation:
https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVStart/tree/master/include/SSVStart/BitmapText

Answer (score 1):

While it's not directly implemented (yet), you can do so – as mentioned by Bartek – use `sf::Sprite` for this, but I'd recommend a `sf::VertexArray`.

First you'll need some function to translate any character into coordinates inside your sprite sheet. There are several ways to do this. But for now I'd just settle on doing a simple mapping:

```
std::map<wchar_t, sf::IntRect> glyphs;

glyphs[L' '] = sf::IntRect(0,  0, 24, 24);
glyphs[L'!'] = sf::IntRect(24, 0, 24, 24);
// etc. define everything in your font
```

Note that I didn't measure your *character* sheet above. I just used 24 pixels for demonstration. Of course you could build a mapping like this dynamically when you load the "font".

When drawing using a sf::Sprite you could then just do something like this:

```
sf::Sprite character(myFontTexture);

int x = 0;
for(auto &c : text) {
    auto &glyph = glyphs.find(c);

    // Unknown character not in our mapping?
    if(glyph == glyps.end())
        continue; // skip it!

    // Update the sprite
    character.setTextureRect(glyph);
    character.setPosition(x, 0);

    // Draw it
    window.draw(character);

    // Update the position for the next glyph
    x += glyph.width;
}
```

The approach for an sf::VertexArray is similar, but you'd just construct it glyph by glyph rather than redrawing them all over and over again.

```
int x = 0;
for(auto &c : text) {
    auto &glyph = glyphs.find(c);

    // Unknown character not in our mapping?
    if(glyph == glyps.end())
        continue; // skip it!

    // Specific vertex layout etc. depends on the actual sf::VertexArray
    myVertexArray.append(sf::Vertex2f(sf::Vector2f(x, 0), sf::Vertex2f(glyph.left, glyph.top));
    myVertexArray.append(sf::Vertex2f(sf::Vector2f(x + glyph.width, 0), sf::Vertex2f(glyph.left + glyph.width, glyph.top));
    myVertexArray.append(sf::Vertex2f(sf::Vector2f(x + glyph.width, glyph.height), sf::Vertex2f(glyph.left + glyph.width, glyph.top + glyph.height));
    myVertexArray.append(sf::Vertex2f(sf::Vector2f(x, glyph.height), sf::Vertex2f(glyph.left, glyph.top + glyph.height));
}

// Draw the text
window.draw(myVertexArray);
```

*Note that all this code is untested and from memory, so expect bugs here or there, but it should give you a general idea on how you could do it.*